# Webdriver firefox: does not support xpath with name()

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Webdriver firefox: does not support xpath with name().
For example,

```
WebElement element = ...;
element.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[name()='button' or name()='input']"));
```

This works fine for chrome and edge.

I am using

```
firefox quantum 66.0.3
geckodriver-0.24.0-win64.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
element.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[name()='button' or name()='input']"));
```

vs

```
element.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='button' or name()='input']"));
```

The '.' is for finding child element of a parrent element.

Answer (score 0):

Presemably you are trying to use `findElement(By.xpath(".//*[name()='button' or name()='input']"))` with respect to the previously identified ancestor element `WebElement element = ...;`.

So instead of `.//` you need to use **`./`** as follows:

```
WebElement element = ...;
element.findElement(By.xpath("./*[name()='button' or name()='input']"));
```

Comment: ./ is direct children, not descendant.